# Java - Getting line from file

Tags: java, string, io

Below is my current function. It works fine and returns true if the lineToCompare is found.

```
public static int checkrank(String lineToCompare){
    try{
        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("ranks.txt");

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        //Compare the line with the line to compare (string)
        if(strLine.trim().compareTo(lineToCompare) == 0)
          return true;
        }

        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;

}
```

However, I need it to get the line AFTER the lineToCompare is found.

Here's an example text file:

```
xXPwnageLolXx
1
SomethingTest
0
AnotherSomething
3
```

I need it to find the line of text (lineToCompare), then return the number AFTER the line found. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    //Compare the line with the line to compare (string)
    if(strLine.trim().compareTo(lineToCompare) == 0) {
      //I found it!  Read the next line...
      final String lineAfter = br.readLine();
      return Integer.parseInt(lineAfter);    
    }
}
```

I've edited this snippet to include Dowards suggestion.  The local variable is unnecessary, I'm just leaving it in for readability.

Comment: I should add that you could use .equals instead of compareTo to make this snippet slightly more readable

Comment: while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        //Compare the line with the line to compare (string)
        if(strLine.trim().compareTo(lineToCompare) == 0)
          return new Integer(br.readLine())
        }

Comment: @DorwardVillaruz Yes - if he wishes to return this value I agree.  I left it open in case he wants to do whatever else...

Comment: The OP is quite clear about the question.

I need it to find the line of text (lineToCompare), then return the number AFTER the line found. How would I do this?

But of course it can also be use to do something else. great catch!